# ¿Como "Mezclar" tres arreglos? en PHP

Tags: php, laravel, array

Estoy realizando una aplicación en laravel 6 la cual tiene una relación ManyToMany que esta representada con una tabla pivote la cual contiene cuatro columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El IDArticulo, Precio, y Cantidad provienen desde la vista (de una tabla) en forma de arreglo que obtengo de la request de este modo:

```
$ids = $request->input('IDArticulo');
$precios = $request->input('Precio');        
$cantidades = $request->input('Cantidad');
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haciendo pruebas manualmente me di cuenta que requiero "transformar" esos tres arreglos en uno solo que quede definido de este modo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para después aplicar el método sync y se realice la inserción de la información en la tabla pivote. (Cosa que ya probé y funciona correctamente)

Comment: Podés probar con [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php). Mira el Ejemplo #4 Crear un array de arrays, creo que es mas o menos lo que buscas. Si te trabas con algo actualiza la pregunta con lo que hayas intentado. Y si lo solucionas puedes explicar la solución en una respuesta.

Comment: Ya probé de ese modo @porloscerrosΨ y el "mezclado" no se realiza de forma correcta, intente de este modo for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
            $pivote = [$ids[$i] => ['Precio' => $precios[$i], 'Cantidad' => $cantidades[$i]]];
        } , pero solo me mantiene le ultimo valor

Comment: ¿De dónde salen los precios `100` y `1200` del array final? Me perdí en esa parte.... Esto se puede hacer en PHP claro está, pero me pregunto por qué no traes los datos agrupados desde la consulta. Supongo que al traerlos separados estás ejecutando tres consultas en la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Dados los siguientes arrays:

```
        $ids = [
            0 => '1',
            1 => '2',
            2 => '1',
        ];
        $precios = [
            0 => '1000',
            1 => '1234',
            2 => '1000',
        ];
        $cantidades = [
            0 => '2',
            1 => '1',
            2 => '1',
        ];
```

Por lo que interpreto, está queriendo por un lado:

- Agrupar los tres arrays en un cuarto array que tenga como índice los valores del array `$ids`. Aunque hay muchas funciones en PHP para trabajar sobre arrays, ya que en el comentario dices que has probado con un `for`, sigo por esa línea, sólo que voy a usar `foreach` por comodidad:

```
    $resultado = [];
    foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
        $resultado[$id] = [
            'Precio' => $precios[$key],
            'Cantidad' => $cantidades[$key],
        ];
    }

    print_r($resultado);
    /*
    Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [Precio] => 1000
                [Cantidad] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Precio] => 1234
                [Cantidad] => 1
            )

    )
    */
```

- Pero por otro lado, quieres que no simplemente se agrupen por el valor de `$ids`, sino que cuando haya más de un elemento con ese valor, las cantidades se sumen. Entonces, para hacer esa condición, puedes usar `array_key_exists()`, que devuelve `true/false`, dependiendo de si en el array ya existe ese índice:

```
    $resultado = [];
    foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
        if(array_key_exists($id, $resultado))
            $resultado[$id] = [
                'Precio' => $precios[$key],
                'Cantidad' => $resultado[$id]['Cantidad'] + $cantidades[$key],
            ];
        else
            $resultado[$id] = [
                'Precio' => $precios[$key],
                'Cantidad' => $cantidades[$key],
            ];
    }
    print_r($resultado);
    /*
    Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [Precio] => 1000
                [Cantidad] => 3
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Precio] => 1234
                [Cantidad] => 1
            )

    )
    */
```